# How to Make a Summary Table combine data from Multiple sheets ?

Tags: excel

Dears,

I Would like to ask you how to transferred values automatically from multiple tables in multiple sheets, where this value will be under the same column's name

For Example, I designed a worksheets of month sales Report and create 4 sheets and named it " week 1, Week 2, Week 3,Week 4" this sheet have the same table columns with different contents based the sales information of each week, so in separate sheet I would like to make a summary to some of this columns from each sheet to combine the data in one table with specific columns

Please, Anyone Help ? I'd Be Thankful

Comment: I am not 100% certain of what you are trying to do but if you are wanting to get data from specific sheets then maybe look into INDIRECT references. If you mean sum the same range on different sheets you can treat it like a 3D array by selecting all sheets you want to apply to and then selecting the range on the active sheet (ie summing sheet1 to sheet 4 then highlighting range a1:a8 will sum that range on all the sheets).

Answer (score 0):

Your data architecture is the wrong way around.

You have several sheets for data entry and you want to consolidate them into one report. That will always be hard work. Pivot tables won't work, formula solutions will be almost impossible, so you will need VBA and even then you probably won't be able to avoid constant manual adjustments.

Unless...

... you change the data architecture and enter **all** data into **one** sheet, with a column for date (or week number or some such). Then you can quickly and easily create a pivot table and report on all kinds of aspects of the data, filter by week or other date ranges. You don't need to know anything about VBA or even formulas.

Work **with** Excel, not against it.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, it is nearly doable - just use some tweaks.

What you can do is input the sheet names into one column, say column A: Week 1, Week 2, etc. and then you can use the INDIRECT() function to turn the strings/values in column A (Week 1, week 2, etc.) into a variable.

My source: https://www.xlsoffice.com/excel-functions/lookup-and-reference-functions/convert-text-string-to-valid-reference-in-excel-using-indirect-function/

Since OP said the tables in each sheet are all the same, you'd easily be able to ctrl+d down the same cell value, but for different sheet names.

For example, if your values were in cell B2 in sheet "Week 1" and sheet "Week 2":

```
 Column A     Column B
 Week 1       =INDIRECT(A1&"!$B$2")
 Week 2       =INDIRECT(A2&"!$B$2")
```